# What is the difference between Document ID and Document name in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits), it is specified in one of the bullet points of

> Constraints on document IDs

that it must be no longer than **1500 bytes** and just below that we have

> Maximum size for a document name

must be no longer than **6 KiB**.

I did not find any distinction between **document ID and document name** in the documentation, I think **document ID and document name** are the same, but then the above quotes are conflicting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed it is confusing and buried in the documentation. But I was able to find it in the size calculations website. [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size#:%7E:text=Document%20ID%20size%20The%20size%20of%20a,the%20my_task_id%20document%20ID%2016%20additional%20bytes)

In a nutshell the `document name` is basically the size of the path + `document id` + 16 extra bytes. Whereas `document id` is the one that identifies every document in a collection. Therefore you can't set `document name` manually, it is automatically generated.

It shouldn't be a problem in the most cases, unless you have a very nested collection structure and long `document id`s. But keep in mind this is not affected with long or deeply nested fields, it only apply to `document id`s. But in that case you will be affected with the `maximum document size`.

Example from the link above to calculate it:

> For a document in the subcollection users/jeff/tasks with a string
> document ID of my_task_id, the document name size is 6 + 5 + 6 + 11 +
> 16 = 44 bytes:
>
> 6 bytes for the users collection ID
>
> 5 bytes for the jeff document ID
>
> 6 bytes for the tasks collection ID
>
> 11 bytes for the my_task_id document ID
>
> 16 additional bytes

Comment: Thanks for digging that up Mohammad, as it has me stumped for a moment. 

Comment: Yeah me too XD, Most welcome, glad I was able to help 